# ffmpeg-static error on gcp cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions, video-processing

```
const ffmpegPath = require('ffmpeg-static');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function extractFrames(inputFile, outputFile, fps = 0.1) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const ffmpeg = spawn(ffmpegPath, [
            '-i', inputFile,
            '-vf', `fps=${fps}`,
            outputFile
        ]);

        ffmpeg.on('close', resolve);
        ffmpeg.on('error', reject);
    });
}
```

This code is giving an error of `Uncaught signal: 11, pid=15, tid=15, fault_addr=99.` on gcp cloud functions, I'm trying to save frames in "/tmp" folder. But, I'm getting this error.

My ffmpeg-static version is : 5.2.0

While running on localhost, this is working perfectly fine. But, it on gcp, it is giving error.

Comment: see [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you are getting, it seems to be an issue with the library version.

I would suggest you to review this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/SavageCore/node-ffprobe-installer/issues/121#issuecomment-1726774051) which suggests to use an older version of node.js. Also check whether the installed versions are compatible with the library version you are using. Also it seems like an open issue, which is not a complete answer but a workaround.

> Encountering this problem in Google Cloud Functions, 2nd Gen, with Node 20 on Ubuntu 22.04. Discouraging to see how long this seems to have been an issue for people.

> Given that people are reporting that this works with older versions of Node and/or Ubuntu, I'm wondering if this is more-so an issue with ffmpeg or Node (or both). Downgrading to older versions isn't an attractive long-term solution so I'm trying to do a little more digging to see if I can find any indication of the root of the problem here.

Also check this another [Github Link](https://github.com/eugeneware/ffmpeg-static) to know the supported version environment of `ffmpeg-static`. I can see that you are using the `ffmpeg-static` 5.2.0 version but the as per this [Github Link](https://github.com/eugeneware/ffmpeg-static/releases/tag/b6.0) the latest using version of `ffmpeg-static` is 6.0.